# .scroll-pane как сделать чтобы после reinitialise не достигал верха без unbind

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

    var settings = {
        showArrows: true
    };

    var api = $(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane(settings).data('jsp');

    $(".scroll-pane").bind('jsp-scroll-y',function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom){

        if(isAtTop) {
            $("#status").prepend("isAtTop"); // как заставить не срабытывать этот блог после reinitialise но без отмены события unbind //
        }

    });

    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){

        //api.getContentPane().prepend('<p>This is paragraph number '+i++'</p>');
        api.getContentPane().append("<p>1</p>");

        $(".scroll-pane").unbind('jsp-scroll-y');

        api.reinitialise({autoReinitialise: false , maintainPosition: true, stickToBottom : true});
        api.scrollToBottom(true);

        $(".scroll-pane").bind('jsp-scroll-y',function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
            if(isAtTop) {
                $("#status").prepend("isAtTop");
            }
        });
        count++;
        if(count==4)clearInterval(interval);
    },1000);
});
```